# Having an issue with JQuery interfering with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a WordPress site that has a gallery built in Javascript. I have created some JQuery code for my site and it works, except now the gallery shadowbox no longer pulls up. I removed the JQuery I wrote and it worked, tried to put it back in and it stopped working again . I have done some searching and found some suggestions but as described below none of them have worked.

This is the code I wrote:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>


jQuery(function ($) {

  $(window).load(function() {

    if ( $('.home').length) { 

    $(window).scroll(function() {
      var height = $(window).scrollTop();
          if(height  > 500 ) {
            $('#wrapper-7').addClass( "wrapper-7-changed" ); 
            $('.wrapper-mirroring-7').addClass( "wrapper-mirroring-7-changed" ); 
            $('.social-icon').addClass( "social-icon-changed" ); 
            $('#block-7 li.widget').addClass( "widget-changed" );

            $('#block-1').addClass( "block-1-changed" );

            $('#block-9').addClass( "block-9-changed" );

            $('#wrapper-6').addClass( "wrapper-6-changed" );
            $('.wrapper-mirroring-6').addClass( "wrapper-mirroring-6-changed" );

          } else {
            $('#wrapper-7').removeClass( "wrapper-7-changed" );
            $('.wrapper-mirroring-7').removeClass( "wrapper-mirroring-7-changed" ); 
            $('.social-icon').removeClass( "social-icon-changed" );
            $('#block-7 li.widget').removeClass( "widget-changed" );
            $('#block-1').removeClass( "block-1-changed" );
            $('#block-9').removeClass( "block-9-changed" );
            $('#wrapper-6').removeClass( "wrapper-6-changed" );
            $('.wrapper-mirroring-6').removeClass( "wrapper-mirroring-6-changed" );
          }   

       });

    } else {

    $(window).scroll(function() {
      var height = $(window).scrollTop();
          if(height  > 50 ) {
            $('#wrapper-7').addClass( "wrapper-7-changed" ); 
            $('.wrapper-mirroring-7').addClass( "wrapper-mirroring-7-changed" ); 
            $('.social-icon').addClass( "social-icon-changed" ); 
            $('#block-7 li.widget').addClass( "widget-changed" );

            $('#block-1').addClass( "block-1-changed" );

            $('#block-9').addClass( "block-9-changed" );

            $('#wrapper-6').addClass( "wrapper-6-changed" );
            $('.wrapper-mirroring-6').addClass( "wrapper-mirroring-6-changed" );

          } else {
            $('#wrapper-7').removeClass( "wrapper-7-changed" );
            $('.wrapper-mirroring-7').removeClass( "wrapper-mirroring-7-changed" ); 
            $('.social-icon').removeClass( "social-icon-changed" );
            $('#block-7 li.widget').removeClass( "widget-changed" );
            $('#block-1').removeClass( "block-1-changed" );
            $('#block-9').removeClass( "block-9-changed" );
            $('#wrapper-6').removeClass( "wrapper-6-changed" );
            $('.wrapper-mirroring-6').removeClass( "wrapper-mirroring-6-changed" );
          }   

       });



    }

  });

}); 
</script>
```

I even tried adding `$.noConflict();` and it did not do anything, I also changed to remove $ from my JQuery and this is what I changed it to and it still makes the gallery not work

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

    if ( jQuery('.home').length) { 

    jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
      var height = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
          if(height  > 500 ) {
            jQuery('#wrapper-7').addClass( "wrapper-7-changed" ); 
            jQuery('.wrapper-mirroring-7').addClass( "wrapper-mirroring-7-changed" ); 
            jQuery('.social-icon').addClass( "social-icon-changed" ); 
            jQuery('#block-7 li.widget').addClass( "widget-changed" );
            jQuery('#block-1').addClass( "block-1-changed" );
            jQuery('#block-9').addClass( "block-9-changed" );
            jQuery('#wrapper-6').addClass( "wrapper-6-changed" );
            jQuery('.wrapper-mirroring-6').addClass( "wrapper-mirroring-6-changed" );
          } else {
            jQuery('#wrapper-7').removeClass( "wrapper-7-changed" );
            jQuery('.wrapper-mirroring-7').removeClass( "wrapper-mirroring-7-changed" ); 
            jQuery('.social-icon').removeClass( "social-icon-changed" );
            jQuery('#block-7 li.widget').removeClass( "widget-changed" );
            jQuery('#block-1').removeClass( "block-1-changed" );
            jQuery('#block-9').removeClass( "block-9-changed" );
            jQuery('#wrapper-6').removeClass( "wrapper-6-changed" );
            jQuery('.wrapper-mirroring-6').removeClass( "wrapper-mirroring-6-changed" );
          }   

       });

    } else {

    jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
      var height = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
          if(height  > 50 ) {
            jQuery('#wrapper-7').addClass( "wrapper-7-changed" ); 
            jQuery('.wrapper-mirroring-7').addClass( "wrapper-mirroring-7-changed" ); 
            jQuery('.social-icon').addClass( "social-icon-changed" ); 
            jQuery('#block-7 li.widget').addClass( "widget-changed" );

            jQuery('#block-1').addClass( "block-1-changed" );

            jQuery('#block-9').addClass( "block-9-changed" );

            jQuery('#wrapper-6').addClass( "wrapper-6-changed" );
            jQuery('.wrapper-mirroring-6').addClass( "wrapper-mirroring-6-changed" );

          } else {
            jQuery('#wrapper-7').removeClass( "wrapper-7-changed" );
            jQuery('.wrapper-mirroring-7').removeClass( "wrapper-mirroring-7-changed" ); 
            jQuery('.social-icon').removeClass( "social-icon-changed" );
            jQuery('#block-7 li.widget').removeClass( "widget-changed" );
            jQuery('#block-1').removeClass( "block-1-changed" );
            jQuery('#block-9').removeClass( "block-9-changed" );
            jQuery('#wrapper-6').removeClass( "wrapper-6-changed" );
            jQuery('.wrapper-mirroring-6').removeClass( "wrapper-mirroring-6-changed" );
          }   

       });



    }

</script>
```

I do not have the code for the gallery, but any help in how to help debug it or change my code so both can work would be helpful.

Comment: Console errors? A common mistake is including jQuery twice. I seem to recall that WordPress ships with jQuery.

Comment: Are you using wp_enqueue_script http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script to enqueue your scripts?